# When pasting the different style of text then TextView and EditText do not support

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

When pasting the different styles of text then TextView and EditText do not support it.

When I am pasting this text to my Edittext then it does not support

---

---

**My EditText and TextView show something like this:**

[image: this is the image that does not support]

**My Code**

```
/...

TextView t1; //initalized
EditText et; //initalized
t1.setText(et.getText().toString());

.../
```

Comment: How are you passing styles in TextView , please attach the code for the same

Comment: ok @Nitish simply get the text that the user paste in `edit text` and get that text and set it to the `TextView`

Comment: Ok like we do in webpages? I don't think these are supported by android , this is feature of Html/css , Either you need to set text from `Html.fromHtlm` or set the `fontFamily` in your textview for particular text

Comment: @Nitesh yes, I tried it `Html.fromHtml` but didn't work.

Comment: No, I don't want to set a `particular text or font` I just want if the user pastes any type of font or style or emoji or whatever just is should display that thing in `textView`